# should I care about this kind of optimization - jQuery - DOM changes

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I have simple question if worths to "cache" DOM changes even outside if the loop (for cycle,..) In case I have e.g. 1000 upcoming changes it makes huge performance boost (as I have heard, not measured myself), but what if I only replacing content like this?

```
jQuery("#subMenu").html( jQuery( html ).find( "#subMenu" ).html() );
jQuery("#pageMain").html( jQuery( html ).find( "#pageMain" ).html());
jQuery("#text").html( jQuery( html ).find( "#text" ).html());
```

I can do this

```
var cachedDOM = jQuery("body").html(); //edited
jQuery(cachedDOM).find("#pageMain").html( jQuery( html ).find( "#pageMain" ).html());
jQuery("body").html(cachedDOM);
```

It would be propably faster, but I need than rebind all of my events, and so on..
Is it really better approach to cache DOM in this case? I dont think so, but I'd like to make the page as quick as possible(especially in older IEs)

Thanks

Comment: The first think you should know about speed is that you can only really say how much (if at all) faster it is, is by testing. Run some tests with your old and with your new code, and see how much quicker it is -if at all-. Then decide if it is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use JQuery's built-in selectors vs trying to 'cache' and traverse a variable. It's counter-intuitive to start your traversal from the body anyway.

Proof the selectors are ridiculously faster than pseudo-caching: http://jsperf.com/pseudo-dom-cache

Comment: His cache code is incorrect and is cloning the entire body. That's why it was slower. In reality caching will be faster.

Comment: It's all cached anyway. It's all on the client-side and the DOM is already rendered. JQuery doesn't fetch a new DOM, it traverses the existing DOM which is what cache is. Now, if we were talking about creating temp variables to store calculations outside of iterations, that'd be another story.

Comment: It's caching the result of the selector that saves time, I don't think he mention client-server network caching anywhere

Comment: Caching the result of the body to then traverse and `find()` some node with an ID? Come on man ;)

Comment: OK..interesting, its really much much faster..interesting that even this is quiet same fast http://jsperf.com/dom-cache

Comment: And I need cache whole body because of changes in DOM are across all of it..not only specific node

Answer (score 2):

Your second code doesn't even make since.

`$var cachedDOM = jQuery("body").html();`

I think you meant

`var $cachedDOM = jQuery("body").html();`

Then this line:

`jQuery(cachedDOM)` is relatively **slow**

You are effectively cloning the entire HTML of you web page on that line, so you can search through it like a normal DOM. It would be a lot faster to use your first method. I think the kind of caching you're looking for, which does give a variable speed boost is something like:

```
var $body = jQuery("body");
$body.find("#pageMain").html($body.find("#pageMain").html());
```

The speed boost depends on how complicated the selector is. For example, since most versions of IE do not have a `document.getElementsByClassName()` function for jQuery to take advantage of, a selector with a lot of classes would be quite slow and a good idea to cache the result. An example of this is: `jQuery("div.left-column.highlighted li.link-list a.active");` If you run a line like that 1000 times in IE with a fairly complicated DOM compared to caching it once and using the cache 999 times you can get a noticeable speed difference.

Comment: yep, it was wrong, I meant `var cachedDOM = jQuery("body").html();`
the main idea was, that when I change something in live DOM (visible webpage), browser must render all changes, and when I'm making more changes at once, it should be faster, than make first change -> render page, then make second change -> render page, …
but it seems that is not true..
thanks